# What is the difference between Reactjs and Rxjs?

Tags: reactjs, rxjs

Basically I am start learning Rxjs and I am a little bit confused between React and Rxjs. I was supposing that Reactjs and Rxjs is same.

**Questions:**

1. If Reactjs and Rxjs is the same then why are we using Reactjs over Rxjs or vise versa?
2. If Reactjs and Rxjs not same, then please briefly differentiate both the languages.

Comment: React is mostly the view layer http://blog.andrewray.me/flux-for-stupid-people/. To manage data flow, you need a data library, like rxjs, redux mobx, flux, etc.

Comment: They sound the same, but actually they are very different

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This is really different, React is view library and Rxjs is reactive programming library for javascript. You can use Rxjs inside react view but in reactjs, people usually use a library like Redux, flux, mobx or relayjs (if they use graphql) for data flow.

Comment: Its worth mentioning that `reactjs` is the facebook JS thing, while `RxJS` got nothing to do with facebook. Rx mean ReactiveX http://reactivex.io/

Answer (score 25):

ReactJs is a view library UI.
ReactiveX or rxjs is a concept, methods or patterns for asychronous programming

Answer (score 22):

**RxJS** is a library that allows us to easily create and manipulate streams of events and data. This makes developing complex but readable asynchronous code much easier.

Creating large asynchronous applications is not the easiest thing to do. We have all witnessed the issues callback hell can cause. Due to this growing concern, people have taken it upon themselves to improve the asynchronous JavaScript landscape. We have all heard of promises, generators, and async/await. There is another solution, and it is called RxJS.

[Reference Link](https://medium.com/@auth0/understanding-reactive-programming-and-rxjs-dad3073e2266)

---

**ReactJS**
In the simple and popular term, React is the V (View) in MVC (Model/View/Controller).

React is a JavaScript library (from Facebook) that is used to render views (for example, HTML pages) dynamically based on some state, which is often in the form of data. React then updates the generated views whenever the original state changes. React is a small but powerful library, with the power being more in the concepts than in the implementation.

[Reference Link](https://edgecoders.com/what-exactly-is-react-js-d04ebfb5c610)

Answer (score 19):

**React** is a javascript library for building user interfaces and makes it painless to create interactive UIs.

**RxJS** is a javascript library for reactive programming using Observables and makes it painless to compose asynchronous or callback-based code.

***Both these javascript libraries are not comparable to each other since they serve different purposes, but together they can create better single-page applications.***