# How to combine "IObservable<bool> IsActive" and "bool IsEnabled" in one subsciption

Tags: c#, reactive-programming, system.reactive, rx.net

Having two properties, one of type `public IObservable<bool> IsEnabled { get; set; }` and the second `public bool IsActive { get;set; }` and I want to combine the two properties in one using `System.Reactive` like that `public bool IsActiveAndEnabled {get;set;}`

```
public class BindableProperty<T> 
{
    T Value { get; }
}

public class Manager
{
    public IObservable<bool> IsEnabled { get; set; }

    public BindableProperty<bool> IsActiveAndEnabled { get; set; }


    private bool isActive;
    public bool IsActive
    {
        get { return isActive; }
        set
        {
            isActive = value;
            // Call OnPropertyChanged whenever the property is updated
            OnPropertyChanged(() => IsActive);
        }
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(Func<bool> property)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Manager()
    {
        IsEnabled
            .And(/* accept only observable, but I want to join with IsActive*/)
            .Then((isEnabled,isActive) => IsActiveAndEnabled = isEnabled && isActive);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a worthy goal. Where are you stuck? Can you show us your actual code rather than just a handful of property signatures?

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: Hi @Enigmativity, I've provided more information, hope I was clear.

Comment: Are you sure you want to put a single scalar value in your `IObservable<T>` instead of a subject type?

Comment: It's not clear what `BindableProperty<T>` is or how to update it, so I'll just assume a normal property in the form of `public bool IsActiveAndEnabled { get; private set; }`. In that case does `IsEnabled.StartWith(true).Subscribe(isEnabled => IsActiveAndEnabled = isEnabled && isActive);` work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The code you've posted is not a good example of how use the Reactive-programming paradigm.

  - Please don't think of an "Observable" as a view over a single scalar-valued member property of a class a *mutable* object.

    - I blame Microsoft for people getting this misunderstanding because they added `ObservableCollection` to the .NET Framework ages ago, but their (mis)use of the term "Observable" in the context of `ObservableCollection` is completely unrelated to the meaning of `Observable` in Reactive programming.
- When doing Reactive programming, an Observable is a source (or emitter) of a stream of data objects (note that a stream *can* be empty (never emitting anything) or only ever emit a single object before it closes itself, or emits thousands of objects every second).
- So an `IObservable` is better thought of as an "`IEnumerable<T>`-that-pushes" (compared to the normal `IEnumerable<T>` which has "pull" semantics).
- The other important thing is that the objects emitted by an Observable should (nay **must**) be immutable! - or at least, the objects emitted must not share mutable state with any other emitted object!

  - This is because if a value changes over time - or if writing a change to one object affects other objects - then other parts of your program that are using a different instance of a returned object will have their state mutated without them expecting it.

I strongly recommend following a guide or tutorial on the concepts of Reactive programming before continuing further. Most of the guides and tutorials cover RxJS (Reactive Extensions for JavaScript, populised after Angular decided to use `Observable<Response>` instead of `Promise<Response>` for their built-in HTTP client librar. While many of the guides cover RxJS they are fully applicable to Reactive Programming for other platforms, such as .NET (while `IObservable<T>` is part of the .NET Framework, you will need the separate Reactive Extensions library to do reactive programming properly and without reinventing the wheel).

Important note: [Reactive Extensions, RxJS and Reactive programming have absolutely nothing to do with "React"/"ReactJS" and the React-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41670972/what-is-the-difference-between-reactjs-and-rxjs/41671303) (there is a tangental relation, but they are completely separate things).

Resources:

- An introduction: https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754
- https://www.learnrxjs.io/
- http://reactivex.io/tutorials.html
- Reactive Extensions for .NET: https://github.com/dotnet/reactive

As for your case, this is my recommendation:

### If `class Manager` must be mutable:

- Remove `public IObservable<bool> IsEnabled { get; set; }`
- Define a new **immutable** `class ManagerState`.
- Extend `class Manager : IObservable<ManagerState>`
- Every time a mutable property in `class Manager` changes, fire-off a new `ManagerState` (populated with a snapshot copy of `Manager`)  to the subscribers.

### If `class Manager` can be made immutable:

- Remove `public IObservable<bool> IsEnabled { get; set; }`
- Define a new class `ManagerSource` which implements `IObservable<Manager>`
- Every time a `Manager` is updated somehow, fire-off a new `Manager` object (populated with a snapshot copy of `Manager`)  to the subscribers.

### Example (when `class Manager` is mutable):

```
class Manager : IObservable<ManagerState>
{
    private Boolean isEnabled; // backing field
    public Boolean IsEnabled
    {
        get { return this.isEnabled; }
        set
        {
            this.isEnabled = value;
            this.NotifySubscribers();
        }
    }

    private Boolean isActive; // backing field
    public Boolean IsActive
    {
        get { return this.isActive; }
        set
        {
            this.isActive = value;
            this.NotifySubscribers();
        }
    }

    #region Observers (Subscribers) handling:

    private readonly ConcurrentBag<IObserver<ManagerState>> subscribers = new ConcurrentBag<IObserver<ManagerState>>();

    private void NotifySubscribers()
    {
        ManagerState snapshot = new ManagerState(
            this.IsEnabled,
            this.IsActive,
            // etc
        );

        foreach( IObserver<ManagerState> observer in this.subscribers )
        {
            observer.OnNext( snapshot );
        } 
    }

    #endregion
}

// Represents a snapshot of the state of a `Manager`
class ManagerState
{
    public ManagerState( Boolean isEnabled, Boolean isActive )
    {
        this.IsEnabled = isEnabled;
        this.IsActive  = isActive;
    }

    public Boolean IsEnabled { get; }
    public Boolean IsActive  { get; }
    // any other members, etc
}
```

Note that this *can* be combined with support for `INotifyPropertyChanged` like so (though I think this is a bad idea because supporting multiple ways to accomplish the same thing will end-up confusing your users/consumers/coworkers) - kinda like how `System.Net.Sockets.Socket` has `Accept`, `AcceptAsync`, `BeginAccept`/`EndAccept` because it supports synchronous, and the APM and EAP asynchronous paradigms (but not TPL for some reason).

```
class Manager : IObservable<ManagerState>, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Boolean isEnabled; // backing field
    public Boolean IsEnabled
    {
        get { return this.isEnabled; }
        set
        {
            this.isEnabled = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged( nameof(this.IsEnabled) );
        }
    }

    private Boolean isActive; // backing field
    public Boolean IsActive
    {
        get { return this.isActive; }
        set
        {
            this.isActive = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged( nameof(this.IsActive) );
        }
    }

    #region INotifyPropetyChanged and Observers (Subscribers) handling:

    private readonly ConcurrentBag<IObserver<ManagerState>> subscribers = new ConcurrentBag<IObserver<ManagerState>>();

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged( String name )
    {
        // First, notify users of INotifyPropetyChanged:

        this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( name ) );

        // Then notify users of IObservable:

        ManagerState snapshot = new ManagerState(
            this.IsEnabled,
            this.IsActive,
            // etc
        );

        foreach( IObserver<ManagerState> observer in this.subscribers )
        {
            observer.OnNext( snapshot );
        } 
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Yes and I think MS confused things even further with the introduction of IAsyncEnumerable, which in my opinion tries to fulfill the same purpose as observable streams but with async continuations.

Comment: @Frank imho `IAsyncEnumerable` is very understandable.

Comment: @Asti I feel that while IAsyncEnumerable is understandable, it's conceptually the same as IObservable

Comment: It really isn't. https://stu.dev/content/images/2018/06/async-enum12.png

Comment: @Frank `IAsyncEnumerable` has "pull" semantics, whereas `IObservable<T>` has "push" semantics. It's like the difference between a producer writing to a `Stream` to output data vs. the producer returning its own readable `Stream` subclass to output data.

Comment: @Dai I respectfully disagree. Async is push. Async is literally 'execute this continuation on your push

Comment: @Asti missing quadrant, but respectfully disagree with the proposed model as inconsistent and philosophically unsound

Comment: I agree that Async is mostly syntactic sugar for callbacks. But I do feel like that in AsyncEnumerable the control lies with the consumer (some flow control semantics), and in Observable the control lies with the producer (no backpressure semantics).

Comment: Let's agree to disagree :) The one thing I agree on is that, you sir, are a scholar and a gentleman.

Comment: @Asti Agreed :) one day I will try to find time to untangle this into a blog post. I accept I may be missing some nuance about the intention of asyncenumerable (which makes more sense as async iterable! Observables are also countable!)  But I suspect the difference between observable and asyncenumerable was not properly considered

Comment: You should try converting an `IObservable<T>` into an `IEnumerable<Task<T>>` - at the face of it, it seems like it's easy, but it's actually non-trivial. ;)

Comment: Look forward to that post. If there's a a twitter or something I can follow, I'll do it.

Comment: @Asti I think IObservable and IEnumerable of task is again something different. I also feel that IEnumerable is a misnomer. Enumerable in the sense of 'countable' is quite vague, compared to Java's Iterable. Iterable is very clear. An observable may be countable/enumerable but not 'iterable', as 'to iterate over' is to quite clearly 'pull' from a countable set. But yes, one day I will try to collate my thoughts there and put a little essay together. When I do, I will remember you and post a link here.

Comment: Enumerable is derived from enumerate. If you look at Java's docs for Iterator<T>:
Iterator takes the place of Enumeration in the Java Collections Framework. Iterators differ from enumerations in two ways:
1. Iterators allow the caller to remove elements from the underlying collection during the iteration with well-defined semantics. 2. Method names have been improved.

Comment: Don't get too hung up on the naming. Besides, `IIterable<T>` would have looked  bad. :)

Comment: @Asti + Frank if you're both going to hang-out here, can you at least give me more upvotes? :)

Comment: My only regret is that I have but one upvote to give. (: